# Decimals deviate too much in C++ when converting from euler angles to quaternions

Tags: c++, decimal, precision

I'm working on a 3D Renderer project, for which I want to use Quaternions to describe rotations.
For that I convert from Euler angles to Quaternions. Here is my code for the **Quaternions**:

```
struct Quaternion {
        double w = 1, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

        static Quaternion ToQuaternion(Vector3& vec) {

            double yaw = DegreesToRadians((double)vec.y);
            double pitch = DegreesToRadians((double)vec.x);
            double roll = DegreesToRadians((double)vec.z);

            double cy = cos(yaw * 0.5);
            double sy = sin(yaw * 0.5);
            double cp = cos(pitch * 0.5);
            double sp = sin(pitch * 0.5);
            double cr = cos(roll * 0.5);
            double sr = sin(roll * 0.5);

            Quaternion q;

            q.w = cr * cp * cy + sr * sp * sy;
            q.x = cr * sp * cy + sr * cp * sy;
            q.y = cr * cp * sy - sr * sp * cy;
            q.z = sr * cp * cy - cr * sp * sy;

            return q;

        }

        void Print() {
            std::cout << w << ", " << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << std::endl;
        }
    };
```

Here is **DegreesToRadians**:

```
double BlueBoxEngine::DegreesToRadians(double degrees) {
    return degrees * PI / 180.0;
}
```

And **Vector3** is just defined as:

```
struct Vector3{
   float x, y, z;
};
```

Now my problem is that they sometimes match what the should be, but sometimes they deviate upto 0.05 from what they should be and sometimes they are negative, instead of positive, but their absolute value is right. What can I do to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
It might be worth noting that is use OpenGL, that means I use a right handed coordinate system.

Comment: It seems that you are using a different convention than [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Euler_angles_to_quaternion_conversion), have you double checked your source material about the correct formula?

Comment: @Bob__ I did and I had to switch the order(It has to do with OpenGL's coordinate system), but everything else is the same. But I have no idea why it sometimes works, and sometimes it doesn't. I used https://quaternions.online/ to verify my results, as the coordinate system on the website is the same as the one I use.

Comment: Changing the order of rotations... Sigh. I must admit I'm not able to check whether you did it right or wrong but rotations are not commutative. This is a trap and to come around, convert the Euler angles into a 3x3 rotation matrix (which should be trivial), and use the algorithm to turn that into a quaternion. At least, that implementation would provide a second way to check your impl. against...

Comment: @Scheffs's Cat i know that rotations arent commutative, but i didnt change the order of multiplication, i just changed what x,y and z are respectively, because on wikipedia they used an other coordinate system.

Comment: Stupid question, but how did you define `PI` ? If, for example, `PI = 3.14`, no wonder that the quaternions will deviate a lot... Make sure you have at least 16 decimals.

Comment: You should add a full example along with expected output and actual output.